# Run method inside for loop only once

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to call a method into for loop in a way that when the method finishes executing. The problem is the method is executing too many times due iteration .

```
  for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
    const element = res[index];
    this.newData = element;
    if (this.distance < 10 && this.newData) {
      if (element.status==="created") {

        this.acceptOrder(); <---- l want to run this method only once 
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
```

l want to run method `this.acceptOrder()` only once if `element.status==="created"` .

Comment: 1 line version `if (this.distance < 10 && res.filter(v => v.status==="created").length) this.acceptOrder()`

Comment: l am getting data from url using firebase firestore snapshot . Every request from firestore snapshot the code above he will check if `element.status==="created"` . So the method is executing too many times due iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to want to continue iterating on the condition `element.status==="created"` for some reason, but only invoke `acceptOrder()`once:

```
let isInvoked = false;
for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
    const element = res[index];
    this.newData = element;
    if (this.distance < 10 && this.newData) {
       if (element.status==="created" && !isInvoked) {
         this.acceptOrder();
         isInvoked = true;
         break; // or return
       }
    }
}
```

Assuming you need to exit as soon as conditions are met after executing `acceptOrder()` only once:

```
for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
    const element = res[index];
    this.newData = element;
    if (this.distance < 10 && this.newData && element.status==="created") {
      this.acceptOrder();
      break; // or return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add variable flag set it into 0; for example;

```
var flag = 0;
 
for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
    const element = res[index];
    this.newData = element;
    if (this.distance < 10 && this.newData) {
      if (element.status==="created") {
        if(flag==0){
            this.acceptOrder();
            flag = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The break after the class method call should "break out" from the for loop so you do need an additional counter variable and add cyclomatic complexity to the program